# Copying a series in a pandas dataframe to a new series

Tags: pandas, dataframe, copy-paste

I'm looking to do the equivalent of a cut and paste in Excel but can't seem to find the right code for it. Everything i read is about concatenation but I'm looking to take 3 series of data of 10 rows each, as an example, and make 1 series of 30 rows in a new df. Thanks.

Comment: `pd.concat` is one way and it will cut and paste the three rows on top of each other like Excel.

Comment: `pd.concat[df1,df2,df3])` then specify your axis `1` = columns `0` = rows.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)